# simplexml_load_file error/warning handling not working

Tags: php

I am having problems with the following:

```
$xml4 = simplexml_load_file($fulllink4, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING);
```

$fulllink4 is dynamically generated. Sometimes the URL that is generated inside $fulllink4 is malformed and I get an error as follows :

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://xxxx.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in D:\xxxx.php on line 90
```

I had read that by adding the ", 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING);" part to the line that it should suppress any errors, but it does not.

Does anyone know how I can completely suppress all errors  generated by that line?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's generally a bad idea but you could get away with `@simplexml_load_file(...)`

Comment: XML file itself missing in that case. So what's the use of suppressing that warning?

Comment: Actually I have just noticed taht I can add @ to simplexml_load_file but I still get notices as follows : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xxxx.php on line 96

How can I get rid of the notices also?

Comment: @samuel, you were quick, I just added that but still get the notices, can I suppress these also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$xml4 = simplexml_load_file($fulllink4, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING & LIBXML_NOERROR);
```

It might also be (probably) that the error/warning your are seeing is being generated 
long before the XML is actually parsed (ie, during the fetch stage, which most likely happens via PHP's standard stream wrappers, ie, file_get_contents() and the like )

You probably should check out this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php

Comment: Thanks, I have added that as follows:

$xml4 = @simplexml_load_file($fulllink4, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING & LIBXML_NOERROR);

This seems to work, but I now get a Notice error  from this line:

$largeimg = $xml4->artist->image[2];

Presumably because the simplexml_load_file failed...

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. If the XML can't be loaded then there is nothing to parse

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to suppress the errors using `@`, but is highly regarded as a bad idea.

```
if($xml4 = @simplexml_load_file($fulllink4, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING)){
    // all other references to $xml4
}
```